How to Show Fully Customized Notification In Android 12 Like telegram
I added a custom layout to show the sender photo in notification just like telegram , but the custom view is added after a leaving a default padding . This is happening for behavioural changes in Android 12 or higher version. But Other app like telegram is still showing customized view. How can I achieve this view in my app. My code for building notification and custom layout is added below.
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/senderAvatarNotification"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_icon_single" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/conversationTitleNotification"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Conversation title" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/senderNameNotification"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sender:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/messageTextNotification"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Line2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:text="Message" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_not_icon)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setContentIntent(getPendingIntent(notificationMessage.unreadCount))
            .setGroup("MyApp")
            .setCustomContentView(notificationLayout)
            .setStyle(messagingStyle)
            .setNumber(notificationMessage.unreadCount)
            .setAutoCancel(true)

I want notification as telegram but i am getting like this. How should I get it?Example Image 1example Image 2
